# C++ Raylib how to detect the side of a rectangle that a circle has collided with

Tags: c++, collision-detection, raylib

I can use the function `CheckCollisionCircleRec(Vector2{ x, y }, radius, paddleRect)` to find out simply if my circle has collided with my rectangle, but I want to be able to find out what side of the rectangle my circle has collided with. How would I go about doing this? None of the algorithms I've made are working. Example of my most recent blunder:

```cpp
if (x - radius <= 0 || x + radius >= screenWidth) {
            speedX *= -1;
        }
        else if (y - radius <= 0 || y + radius >= screenHeight) {
            speedY *= -1;
        }
        else if (CheckCollisionCircleRec(Vector2{ x, y }, radius, paddleRect)) {
            float paddleBottom = paddleRect.y + paddleRect.height;
            float paddleRight = paddleRect.x + paddleRect.width;

            if (range(paddleRect.x, paddleRect.x + speedX / 100, x + radius)) {
                x = paddleRect.x - radius;
                speedX *= -1;
            }
            if (range(paddleRight - speedX / 100, paddleRight, x - radius)) {
                x = paddleRight + radius;
                speedX *= -1;
            };

            if (range(paddleRect.y, paddleRect.y + speedY / 100, y + radius)) {
                y = paddleRect.y - radius;
                speedY *= -1;
            }
            if (range(paddleBottom - speedY / 100, paddleBottom, y - radius)) {
                y = paddleBottom + radius;
                speedY *= -1;
            };
```

EDIT:
Here's the function I used to get the working end result:

```cpp
// px and py are the ball's previous locations
// x and y are the ball's current locations

void checkCollision(Rectangle rectangle) {

    int left = rectangle.x;
    int right = rectangle.x + rectangle.width;
    int top = rectangle.y;
    int bottom = rectangle.y + rectangle.height;

    if (CheckCollisionCircleRec(Vector2{ x, y }, radius, rectangle)) {

        if (px < left) {
            speedX = negative(speedX);
            x = left - radius;
        }
        else if (px > right) {
            speedX = positive(speedX);
            x = right + radius;
        }
        else if (py < top) {
            speedY = negative(speedY);
            y = top - radius;
        }
        else if (py > bottom) {
            speedY = positive(speedY);
            y = bottom + radius;
        };
    };
};
```

Comment: _"None of the algorithms I've made are working"_ show your code and maybe we can help identify the problem.

Comment: And what happens when you set a breakpoint in your debugger inside that first "range" test where you negate `speedX` and then step through the remainder of the cases?  Do you hit multiple cases (_i.e._ negate it twice)?  What is the actual behavior you're seeing that's causing you to ask this question?  Since speeds can be positive or negative, why do you sometimes subtract it?

Comment: The behavior that's making me ask this question is that the ball bounces off the top and the left of the paddle perfectly and doesn't from the right or the bottom. It doesn't even get detected. Is there really not a function in Raylib that also returns the side of the rectangle that the circle collided with? Damn :/

Comment: If you think about it, a collision can be _anywhere_.  It might intersect any number of edges of the rectangle simultaneously.  Then, why should it be up to an engine to try and divine some strategy and make a super complicated interface to represent all the possibilities?   The weird thing about your code is that it _looks_ like "speed" is something that applies to the ball, but then "range" tests are all applying speed to the position of the paddle in a non-obvious way.  Your question is written as if we should understand what your game is, how the paddle / ball move, and what should happen.

Comment: Sorry, I was so into trying to solve this issue I completely forgot to properly structure my question. My game is an Atari Breakout clone; the ball bounces off the walls and the paddle (located at the bottom of the screen following the mouse's X position). I'll need to re-use this collision detection when I implement the bricks that the ball breaks so this is really important to my project. Also, you make a really good point. At first glance, simply finding the side a ball collided with seems like no big deal. When actually coding it, though, it's damn near impossible for a noob like me.

Comment: Yeah, one of the problems I notice here with beginners is they tend to develop very complicated ways to solve a simple problem.  The data representation and semantics is often not planned out coherently...  Often that's because they try to think in code first, instead of solving the overall problem intuitively and then translating that to code.  As a result the code tends to be difficult to understand, prone to bugs, poorly structured and documented, and that just adds to the struggle.  Keep at it, and as you gain experience, you'll start writing code that's easy to understand, debug and fix.

Comment: By the way, the edit you made shows great progress in writing clear, maintainable code.  It is 500% more readable and understandable than your original code.  Well done! :)

Comment: Oh, thank you very much! I'm glad to hear it, going from Python to C++ made it a lot easier for me to spaghetti code everything I wrote so I'm glad to hear I'm making progress. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simply way is to use the PREVIOUS location of your circle. Not sure if you can in your program, but since you have an x and y handy, I'll assume you can have a prevX and prevY. I'll also assume these values represent the CENTER of the circle.

Now if (prevX < paddleRect.x), then you likely collided with the left side (not guaranteed, but resolving ambiguities with complete accuracy requires recursively simulating your physics at smaller and smaller timesteps, which is likely unnecessary here). You can also constrain this more tightly with something like if (prevX < paddleRect.x && prevY > paddleRect.y && prevY < paddleRect.y + paddRect.height). There are various constraints you can add depending on how cleanly you want the side to be hit before detecting it. You can add corner hits, etc.

The reason for using the previous location is that, if your circle is moving fast enough, then in a single frame it can jump straight into the middle of the rectangle. It's usually necessary to use the previous position to give more specific collision information in the current-location collision

Comment: This seems like a really good idea, I'd never thought of storing an object's previous location before but it seems like it should work pretty well. I did think of the clipping problem, though, and instead of storing the previous location of the ball, I'd try and move it back out the paddle (obviously a really dumb decision now that I'm looking at it). Thanks for the idea, I'll try and implement it now and let you know how it gets on.

Comment: Just tried it; works like a charm. Thank you very much :)